# How to get response header from POST request response

Tags: angular, http, http-headers

As above.
Following code doesn't work:

```
public login() {
  const username = "kamczi";
  const password = "password";
    return this.http.post<any>(environment.api_endpoint+'/login', { username, password} , {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(resp=>{
        this.handleAuthentication(resp.headers.get('Authorization'))
    })
  }
  public handleAuthentication(token: string): void {
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', token);
    console.log(token);
  }
```

`Console.log` displays null

I need to get my authorization header which is located in my response header.

[image]

SOLVE

I needed to add following code to my spring boot security conf.

```
CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
configuration.addExposedHeader("Authorization"); // this line helped
```

Comment: Can you show us the response in browser network tab when request is made(with headers) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Angular code is working fine. Some headers are meant to be intercepted by browsers only and user can't access them inside code. To do so you have to explicitly expose them in your response.

So you need to add the following header to the response when you send it from your API and the `Authorization` header will be available.

```
'access-control-expose-headers' : 'Authorization'
```